# Wifi and Bluetooth headset issues

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I am using Qualcomm Atheros AR9565 card and when I use bluetooth headset, wifi slows down. I tried to disable Bluetooth collaboration on windows but I didn't find any option on windows. I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS installed on my lenovo g50-70 laptop.

EDIT:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:4026]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Does it slow down on Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6 on both.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi and stream audio using bluetooth, it is generally normal that Wi-Fi slows down. Bluetooth uses the same frequency.

You can enable bluetooth coexistence on Ubuntu, but it is not perfect either.

It can  be enabled by a terminal command

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf <<< "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1"
```

Reboot to apply.

If this setting doesn't help or makes things worse, revert it by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: It didn't create any difference, situation is still worse like around 2mbps when listening to songs on headset but 20mbps when I disconnect the device.

Comment: There is nothing else to suggest with this hardware.

Comment: Alright so every bluetooth device will create problems with my laptop? unless I some how use 5ghz wifi?

Comment: You have a combo Wi-Fi+BT device. If you use another BT device, it may be better.

Comment: You mean a usb bluetooth device for laptop?

Comment: Exactly. Another option is to replace the internal device. You can get a 802.11ac combo device, e.g Intel and replace. I did it for my laptops a couple of times.

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much for explaining. Have a nice day!

Comment: Can you explain why usb bluetooth will solve this issue? using 5ghz makes sense to me.

Comment: It may solve the issue. It will be another device with its own antenna and radio, etc.

Comment: Alright so can you explain why using same device causes issue and separate devices will not?

Comment: I never wrote that "separate devices will not". I wrote that a separate device MAY solve the issue, because it has anoter antenna and is located in another place. This discussion is off-topic here, and there is nothing to add really.